# Why totally positive elements of a number field have a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, roots, extension-field

I heard that in a number field $K$

(let say $K = \mathbb{Q}[X]/P$), the totally positive element (that are sent into $\mathbb{R}^+$  for all morphisms of fields $K->\mathbb{C}$) all have a squareroot in $K \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$ (so, $\mathbb{R}[X]/P$).

In other words, : they are on the form f^2 for  $f \in K \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$.

Would you have a reference that make the demonstration of this claim?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:** my question wasn't precise enough and contained some mistakes  I apology for it. I added some precisions.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Any element of $\Bbb C$ has a square root.

Comment: What do you mean with "have a squareroot" as $2\in K=\Bbb{Q}$ is totally positive

Comment: Sorry! I added some precisions!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite clearly false if you mean that it has a square root in $K$: for instance $2\in \mathbb{Q}$ is obviously totally positive, but has no square root in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Or course any element of $K$ has a square root in a bigger number field $K\subset L$, but that's not very interesting and has nothing to do with positivity.

So in the end I'm not sure what statement you are referring to, it's possible you are confused.

Comment: You're right, i forgot to mebtiob the tebsor product with R. I added some details